# derivative of a tensor A with respect to transpose(A)*A?

Tags: derivatives, tensors, transpose

What is the derivative of $\partial A/\partial ({A^T}A)$ ? Where $A$ is a 3x3 tensor.

(in index notation, I want to find explicit components of ${D_{ijpq}} = \partial {A_{ij}}/\partial ({A_{kp}}{A_{kq}})$ )

**Attempt:**

I have tried through inverse way using the chain rule as below:

$\frac{{\partial \left( {{A_{kp}}{A_{kq}}} \right)}}{{\partial {A_{ij}}}} = \left( {{A_{iq}}{\delta _{jp}} + {A_{ip}}{\delta _{jq}}} \right)$

but as its inverse is not attainable, I think other manipulation is required.

Any comment would be much appreciated!

Comment: unfortunately it would be the solution of an Sylvester equation. Explicit solutions are only available in very particular cases.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for the comment! I didn't even know this is in connection with Sylvester equation.